# Where are my project files stored

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am having some issues with VS C# 2010. Upon create a project I can not seem to locate the project files after saving.

On my laptop they store to C:\Users\james\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects but on my desktop they are being stored in C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\mediaplayer

I can seem to locate this folder, even when using the variable %appData%. There is no Local, or Tempory Projects folder. At least I can't see them.

I much preferred the project being stored in Documents. Is it possible to change this? If not, how can I physically access the folder with my project within it?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this question - I've been puzzled by the same thing myself before now, expecting that when I *build* a project, it will be saved. (I've usually seen it with the Express edition.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you first fully save everything (or exit and choose to save) the project files will be saved in the expected location. It's only in a temporary location until you explicitly save.

Answer (score 26):

You can change default folder for new projects in Visual Studio settings.

1. Click Tools menu
2. Click Options
3. Find "Projects and Solutions"
4. Choose "Project location"

AppData folder is hidden. You have to type its address in address bar manually or you can enable view for hidden files in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 16):

For Visual Studio 2019 & 2017 :

1. Click `Tools` menu
2. Click `Options`
3. Find `Projects and Solutions`
4. Choose `Locations`

and edit the projects location box (the first one)

Answer (score 3):

C:Windows\Users\"username"\source\repos

this the location of all your projects.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Projects are stored in Temporary Projects under some settings only if you never save them. If you save the project (File → Save All) then you can choose where to save it. The default is the Projects folder inside your Documents.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the tab name of any file you have open and select 'open containing folder' to get there quickly.

Just thought I'd add this as was annoyed at not seeing the file path names when a file just opens via VS by default. (eg, windows terminal app settings menu)

Answer (score 0):

By default Visual Basic 2010 (Or Visual Studio) doesn't notice you when a project is backed up. You can manually check it

**Project Backup Location:**
You can find the project backed up in `C:\Users\<User Name>\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Backup Files` hope that helps.

**For you case:**
Location to backup project should be `C:\Users\james\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Backup Files\mediaplayer`